# Traefik docker-compose "invalid host header" but working with IP and for another service

Tags: docker-compose, http-headers, traefik

How to fix "invalid host header"?

I got a single node Docker swarm Cluster, on which is running traefik and portainer. Both are running fine with https.

When i try to run a frontend (with the same traefik labels i used in portainer) i get "invalid host header" when calling the url. When i call the frontend by IP and port it works.

Any help is really appreciated.

```
# Problem File : Frontend
version: '3'

networks:
  {{traefik_network_name}}:
    external: true

services:
  frontend_portal:
    image: frontend_portal
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - {{traefik_network_name}}
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network={{ traefik_network_name }}
        - traefik.constraint-label={{ traefik_network_name }}
        - traefik.http.routers.frontend_portal-http.rule=Host(`dashboard.my.domain`)
        - traefik.http.routers.frontend_portal-http.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.frontend_portal-http.middlewares=https-redirect
        - traefik.http.routers.frontend_portal-https.rule=Host(`dashboard.my.domain`)
        - traefik.http.routers.frontend_portal-https.entrypoints=https
        - traefik.http.routers.frontend_portal-https.tls=true
        - traefik.http.routers.frontend_portal-https.tls.certresolver=le
        - traefik.http.services.frontend_portal.loadbalancer.server.port=3000
```

```
# Traefik
version: '3.3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.10
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network={{traefik_network_name}}
        - traefik.constraint-label={{traefik_network_name}}
        - traefik.http.middlewares.admin-auth.basicauth.users={{traefikpassword.stdout}}        
        - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
        - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.rule=Host(`{{traefik_app_name}}.{{app_domain_name}}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.middlewares=https-redirect
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.rule=Host(`{{traefik_app_name}}.{{app_domain_name}}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.entrypoints=https
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls=true
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.service=api@internal
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls.certresolver=le
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.middlewares=admin-auth
        - traefik.http.services.traefik-public.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
    volumes:
services
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - {{ storage_mount_path }}/{{ traefik_subdir }}:/certificates 
    command:
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.constraints=Label(`traefik.constraint-label`, `{{traefik_network_name}}`)
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.swarmmode
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email={{email}}
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/certificates/acme.json
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.tlschallenge=true
      - --accesslog
      - --log
      - --api
    networks:
      - {{traefik_network_name}}
    
networks:
  {{traefik_network_name}}:
    external: true
```

```
# Portainer
version: '3.3'

services:
  agent:
    image: portainer/agent:2.18.4
    environment:
      AGENT_CLUSTER_ADDR: tasks.agent
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes
    networks:
      - {{portainer_network_name}}
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.platform.os == linux

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:2.18.4
    command: "-H tcp://tasks.agent:9001 --tlsskipverify --admin-password {{portainerpassword.stdout}}"
    volumes:
      - {{portainer_volume_name}}:/data
    networks:
      - {{portainer_network_name}}
      - {{traefik_network_name}}
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network={{ traefik_network_name }}
        - traefik.constraint-label={{ traefik_network_name }}
        - traefik.http.routers.portainer-http.rule=Host(`{{portainer_app_name}}.{{app_domain_name}}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.portainer-http.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.portainer-http.middlewares=https-redirect
        - traefik.http.routers.portainer-https.rule=Host(`{{portainer_app_name}}.{{app_domain_name}}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.portainer-https.entrypoints=https
        - traefik.http.routers.portainer-https.tls=true
        - traefik.http.routers.portainer-https.tls.certresolver=le
        - traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port={{portainer_admin_port}}

networks:
  {{portainer_network_name}}:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
  {{traefik_network_name}}:
    external: true

volumes:
  '{{ portainer_volume_name }}':
```